# How to clarify the state of menu item by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, html-lists

I have the following menu :

```
<div>
              <ul class="menu">
                    <li id="2" class="inactive"><a href="frm_Items.aspx" id="lnk_Draft" runat="server">1
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_DraftCount" runat="server" CssClass="counter"></asp:Label></a></li>
                    <li id="3" class="inactive"><a href="#" id="lnk_Inbox" runat="server">2
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InboxCount" runat="server" CssClass="counter"></asp:Label></a></li>
                    <li id="4" class="inactive"><a href="#" id="lnk_Outbox" runat="server">3
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_OutboxCount" runat="server" CssClass="counter"></asp:Label></a></li>
                    <li id="5" class="inactive"><a href="#" id="lnk_Archive" runat="server">4
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ArchiveCount" runat="server" CssClass="counter"></asp:Label></a></li>
                    <li id="6" class="inactive"><a href="#" id="lnk_New" runat="server">5 </a></li>
                    <li id="Li1" class="inactive"><a href="#" id="lnk_Search" runat="server">6 </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

---

I have a css class for `active` and i wanna some jquery to toggle between active and inactive
according to user click.

Comment: Show the code you have already tried

Comment: user click on the <li></li> element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done better with nicer markup but...

```
$("ul > li").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
})
```

Comment: Better `$(this).toggleClass('active incative');`

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.menu li').click(function () {
     $('.menu li').removeClass('active'); // removes class from each li
     $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple toggle :

```
$("li.inactive").click(function() {
    // Toogle the current active li
    $("li.active").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    // Toggle the li you just clicked on
    $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, to make code easier, I would simply toggle from `no-class` (that you are now calling *inactive*) to `active` (and vice-versa)

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
}
```

I supposed you want bind the handler to `<a>` elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.menu > li').click(function(){
      $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

   });

});
```